# ionic app quit and open it again then it requires relaunch and start from beginning

Tags: android, iphone, ionic-framework

I create an Ionic1 application. It works fine.

I can login and logout successfully, all functionalities works fine.

If i login into the app and when i quit the app then open it again. Then it restart/relaunch the app and requires login again.

I can not understand why such thing happens. Please suggest me what is wrong here.